# Visual C# Express and Oracle database Express using entity framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm trying to access my Oracle XE database using Visual C# Express and entity framework.

I've tried installing oracleef (http://oracleef.codeplex.com/) but I'm not getting Oracle EF provider inside Visual C# Express add EF connection wizard, although machine.config contains

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

I've tried using EdmGen2.exe to manually generate EF classes from database, but I had little success.

How can I use Oracle database, Visual C# Express and Entity Framework together?

Comment: if it's interesting to someone, final solution for me was to use NHibernate, FluentNHibernate and NHibernateMappingGenerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Express doesn't support third party components such as DB connection wizards. You will have to configure the connection manually (and create the entity model manually, too... so I suggest you use EF Code First)

Comment: How do we do that? "configure the connection manually", how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You could install the oracle Instant Client with ODP.Net and add Oracle.DataAccess as reference to your project. 
After that you could connect to your database, like this:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

private OracleConnection Connect = new OracleConnection();

public int OracleConnect(string hostname, string username, string password, string servicename)
{
    Connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + hostname + ") (PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" + servicename + ")));" + "User Id=" + username + ";Password=" + password + ";";
    try
    {
        Connect.Open();
        return 0;

    }
    catch (OracleException OracleExeption)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```